# Migrating to firebase from channel api

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase

I am trying to migrate from Channel API in GAE to firebase. To do this, first, I am trying to setup a local development environment. I cloned the sample app from GAE samples. ([Link to sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/firebase-tictactoe))

When I ran this, I get the following error, when the web client is trying to authenticate with the firebase DB.The error is in the console.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkXDm.png)

i.e token authentication failed.Clearly, this points to the fact that generated JWT is not correct.

To be sure, I have done the following:

1. Created a service account in Google cloud console.
2. Downloaded the JSON and pointed to this JSON in the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
3. Put the code snipped from the firebase into WEB-INF/view/firebase_config.jspf file
4. The code to generate the token is as follows ( from FirebaseChannel.java )

   ```
   public String createFirebaseToken(Game game, String userId) {
   final AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
   final BaseEncoding base64 = BaseEncoding.base64();

   String header = base64.encode("{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"alg\":\"RS256\"}".getBytes());

   // Construct the claim
   String channelKey = game.getChannelKey(userId);
   String clientEmail = appIdentity.getServiceAccountName();
   System.out.println(clientEmail);

   long epochTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
   long expire = epochTime + 60 * 60; // an hour from now

   Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   claims.put("iss", clientEmail);
   claims.put("sub", clientEmail);
   claims.put("aud", IDENTITY_ENDPOINT);
   claims.put("uid", channelKey);
   claims.put("iat", epochTime);
   claims.put("exp", expire);
   System.out.println(claims);

   String payload = base64.encode(new Gson().toJson(claims).getBytes());
   String toSign = String.format("%s.%s", header, payload);
   AppIdentityService.SigningResult result = 
   appIdentity.signForApp(toSign.getBytes());
   return String.format("%s.%s", toSign, 
   base64.encode(result.getSignature()));
   }
   ```

Instead of Step #2, have also tried  'gcloud auth application-default login' and then running after unsetting the environment variable - resulting in the same issue

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found out additional info which may help others facing the same issue. I did the following to be able to run the sample locally.

1. Its important to ensure that the service account in appengine has the permissions to access resources. Chose "Editor" as the role for permissions (other levels may also work, but I chose this) for the default appengine service account. This will ensure that you do not run into "Unauthorized" error.
2. My application was enabled for domain authentication and did not use Google authentication. The sample however has been created for Google authentication. I had to make changes to the sample code to send the userId as part of the URL and removed the code that referred to UserServiceFactory.
3. The console error did show up even now, but the application worked fine. This error probably can be ignored. In the deployed environment, however, this error does not show up.

I would appreciate if Google/Firebase engineers update this answer with official responses, or update the sample documentation appropriately as currently this information does not seem to be mentioned anywhere.